# Correct way to require files and sdk in php Linux OS

Tags: php, linux, laravel, amazon-web-services, sendgrid

I am working on my Laravel Project. I am using windows to develop and just uploaded my laravel code to AWS Elasticbeanstalk. I am using AWS SDK for sending notifications and Sendgrid for sending emails.

I am using following codes in my local env to access aws sdk and sendgrid using composer,

```
require __DIR__ . '\composer\vendor\autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '\sendgrid-php\sendgrid-php.php';
require __DIR__ . '\aws\aws-autoloader.php';
```

Its working fine in my windows local environment but on linux it is throwing following error

[image]

I have installed the composer but it still shows the same error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Backslash is no path seperator on linux. Use forward slashes all the time, because they also work on windows.

Comment: @Frieder thanks for your reply. You are right I just checked and its working. Would you please post this as an answer so I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `\` (backslash) as path separator on linux. You can use instead the `/` (forward slash) as separator because that is the accepted seperator for linux and as a side effect windows also accepts this.